# Allow a certain endpoint only internally in Traefik

Tags: server, traefik

I have some services defined in my traefik config file like so

```yaml
services:
    serviceA:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
        - url: http://serviceA:8080

    serviceB:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
        - url: http://serviceB:8080

( more services here...)
```

Services are in docker containers. I want a certain endpoint in serviceB to be only accessible internally.

```yaml
http:
  routers:
    to-admin:
      rule: "Host(`{{env "MYHOST"}}`) && PathPrefix(`/serviceB/criticalEndpoint`)"
      service: serviceB
      middlewares:
      - ?
```

I saw there's a middleware for IP whitelisting, but what IP could I use so all external access to this endpoint is forbidden while the rest of endpoints on the service are public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is `IPWhiteList` middleware which you can attach to your `service`, so it will intercept every request to that service and allow/deny based on the client IP address.

So if you want the service to be exposed internally, you can give the CIDR range of your VPC which will include all possible internal IP addresses.

#### Docker example

```yaml
# Accepts request from defined IP
labels:
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.test-ipwhitelist.ipwhitelist.sourcerange=127.0.0.1/32, 192.168.1.7"
```

#### Kubernetes example

```yaml
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: test-ipwhitelist
spec:
  ipWhiteList:
    sourceRange:
      - 127.0.0.1/32
      - 192.168.1.7
```

`sourceRange` : The `sourceRange` option sets the allowed IPs (or ranges of allowed IPs by using CIDR notation).

`ipStrategy` : The `ipStrategy` option defines two parameters that set how Traefik determines the client IP: `depth`, and `excludedIPs`.

`ipStrategy.depth`: The `depth` option tells Traefik to use the `X-Forwarded-For` header and take the IP located at the depth position (starting from the right).

- If `depth` is greater than the total number of IPs in `X-Forwarded-For`, then the client IP will be empty.
- `depth` is ignored if its value is less than or equal to 0.

Consider the following screenshot

[image]

[Reference Traefik Docs](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/ipwhitelist/)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, do you know if there's a way to whitelist another service defined in traefik instead of providing the IP?

Comment: You can use internal dns for the service. Like for kubernetes its svc.cluster.local. You should also be able to use it for docker. You can also create a Route53 record which will only resolve to internal IP.

Comment: I'll check that out, thanks!